Do smooth morphisms imply regular schemes?
The two questions come from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Example 10.0.3 and the definition of "smooth morphisms".
Question One: in the definition of smooth morphisms, do the notation
$$
\dim_{k(x)} (\Omega_{X/Y} \otimes k(x)) = n
$$
mean the dimension of $\Omega_{X/Y, x} \otimes_{O_{X,x}} k(x)$, y = f(x)? I do not understand the dimension of sheaves, but I do know the dimension of modules.
Question Two: Example 10.0.3 says if $Y = \operatorname{Spec} k$ and $k$ is algebraically closed, then $X$ is smooth over $k$ iff $X$ is regular of dimension $n$. The "if" part is easy using the theorems in chapter II. But how to prove the "only if" part?
If I assume $X$ is also integral, then the "only if" part also comes from the theorems in chapter II. But for a general $X$, I do not know how to prove it.

Hartshorne's treatment on smothness is somewhat awkward. Good references for smooth morphisms are Liu, Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves and Fu, Etale cohomology.

$k(x)$ is a field and can be thought as a sheaf on $X$.
As stated in the question, the case where $X$ is irreducible is easy to prove. Now assume $X$ is of finite type over $k$ and smooth. Assume $X' \subset X$ is an irreducible component. Then locally the ring $O_{X'}$ is a quotient ring of $O_X$, moduling a minimal ideal $I$. For $x \in X'$, $x$ is a prime containing $I$ locally,
$$
\Omega_{X'/Y \otimes_{O_{X'}} k(x)} = \Omega_{X /Y \otimes_{O_X} k(x)}
$$
So the condition (3) holds on $X'$ (although I am not sure if $X'$ is flat over Y). Then (II, 8.8) implies that $X'$ is regular of dimension $n$. By Nakayama's lemma, $X$ is also regular of dimension $n$.
